# Grunt doesn't output main.js

Tags: gruntjs

I have the following:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: '<json:package.json>',
        concat: {
            options: {
              outputStyle: 'minified',
            },
            dist: {
              src: [
                    'js/jquery.min.js', 
                    'js/foundation.min.js',     
                    'js/header.js'
                    ],
              dest: 'js/main.js',
            },
            dist: {
                src: [
                        'scss/foundation.css', 
                        'scss/footer.scss', 
                        'scss/header.scss', 
                        'scss/off_canvas_custom.scss', 
                        'scss/projects_panel.scss', 
                        'scss/typography.scss'
                    ],
                dest: 'css/app.css',
            }
        },
        watch: {
            scripts: {
              files: [
                        'js/jquery.min.js', 
                        'js/foundation.min.js', 
                        'js/header.js'
                        ],
              tasks: ['concat']
            },

            styles: {
                files: [
                        'scss/foundation.css', 
                        'scss/footer.scss', 
                        'scss/header.scss', 
                        'scss/off_canvas_custom.scss', 
                        'scss/projects_panel.scss', 
                        'scss/typography.scss'
                    ],
                tasks: ['concat']
            }
        }

    }

);
};
```

with the following folder structure:

1. index.html

   - JS
   - header.js
   - jquery
   - foundation
   - CSS
   - package.json

and few more files

after typing in my terminal "grunt watch" and I make some changes in header.js [image]

main.js doesn't get outputted at all. It suppose to be outputted inside the JS folder

Comment: where is you `default` task?

Comment: Both of your `concat` task names are the same. Change the one for javascript to `js` and then try it. Otherwise I'll look into this. As @Zamboney says, you should make a default task, include `concat` as a task and run that, this way we know where the problem is.